# An elegant way to join arrays of arrays of strings by two different separators in java by stream

Tags: java

We can use `String.join` to concatenate a list of strings by a separator.

My problem now is I have an array of arrays of strings.

e.g

```
[(a, b), (c, d), (e,f)],
```

I want to join `a&b, c&d, e&f` by colon, and space between these pairs.

like

```
a:b c:d e:f
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Follow up:

If you do this with a loop nested with another loop then you create a lot of String variables in your pool, which does not look very good

Comment: The answer is really no different, you just add a loop to loop through the arrays.

Comment: You say you want to join them by comma and spaces, but then you use an example with a colon. I don't understand

Comment: @Hypino If you do this with a loop nested with another loop then you create a lot of String variables in your pool, which does not look very good.

Comment: @jthort Sorry for my typo

Comment: You could make a method for joining, passing an array and a separator, then first call that on the inner array, collect all results in a new array, and then call that method wth the new array.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you can just stream them to a string joining collector. Simply do this for the "inner" arrays and again on the results.

```
String[][] stringsss = new String[][] {
    {"a", "b"},
    {"c", "d"},
    {"e", "f"}
};
String result = Arrays.stream(stringsss)
    .map(e -> Arrays.stream(e).collect(Collectors.joining(":")))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I wonder whether this creates a lot of intermediate strings in the string pool which I am not interested in. If yes, is there a better way to avoid this?

Comment: A quick look at `java.util.StringJoiner` reveals that it uses a `java.lang.StringBuilder` internally. You get one intermediate result per "inner" array and then there's the final result. If you want a more efficient way, you have to use loops. Then you can control the buffering yourself.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your answer. I know we can use two nested StringBuilders to do it, but I just do not like the intermediate strings produced from the first StringBuilder :p